# HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 , Connection: close

Tags: web-part, web-services

I am getting this error in sharepoint 2010 portal after i restore the site collection for my portal from SharePoint 2010 management shell.

The problem is the restoring process does not complete and i get the following error:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2012
>   12:35:19 GMT Connection: close

any one can help me ...

Comment: i am facing a similar problem. but even after i created a site collection i get the same error.

Comment: Try running PSConfig to upgrade the database to the SP2010 schema.

Answer (score 3):

That's the default screen that you will see when there is no site collection available, but the URL is valid.

Comment: yes the portal dos't have default site , put I try to make a another restoration for site collection and its successfully complete and the portal return run Ok , put i don't know why the first restoration not complete .... At All thank you Mr.rjcup3

Comment: It means the site collection restoration failed. Was there an error during the restore?

Answer (score 1):

Create  the site collection for that webapplication.

Answer (score 1):

In my specific case (in an environment I didn't setup) the event viewer told me that the login failed for the specified user.

[image]

This may cause a security error, if your adding the account to the database. Resolve it by creating the web application with the designated account.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that their is no Site Collection for the Managed Path. Or alternatively the managed path has been changed.

http://dea.nbird.com.au/2013/09/11/sharepoint-2013-http1-1-200-ok-server-microsoft-iis8-0-connection-close-error/

Answer (score 0):

This problem occure if one of the databases could not be found.

When you restore the database the old name may be changed.
Please check your database names again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.Name -eq "Database name"} | Add-SPShellAdmin -Username "domain\admin or service account"
```

Take the quotes off the domain account before running
Set Database Name and domain account
Shell Access missing at least that's what caused my failures from 2013 to 2016 to final home on 2019